# React 18.2.0 Next js 13 - Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match... Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I get this error when I focus on the input element as soon as the page opens. I don't get an error when I wait a few seconds and focus on the input element. I can't solve this error. When I remove the Link components the error is resolved.

Just to be sure, I installed the **LATEST DEFAULT NEXT JS 13.1.5** project and added the input element directly, the same problem continues. [Error image](https://i.ibb.co/48WcFPq/2023-01-25-22-08-16.png)

[Error detailed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVVqt.png)

```
import SectionIdentifier from "components/section-identifier";
import Link from "next/link";

function ProfilePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <SectionIdentifier title={"Sifarişlərim"} description={"Bütün sifarişləriniz burada görünməkdədir. Sifarişlər haqqında məlumat üçün ətraflı yazısına daxil olun."} />
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">

        {/* When i deleted this div section problem is fixed */}
        <div className="flex gap-x-11">
          <Link className="font-medium" href="/asdasd">
            Bütün məhsullar (133)
          </Link>
          <Link className="text-black/50" href="/asdasd">
            Populyar
          </Link>
          <Link className="text-black/50" href="/asdasd">
            Yeni
          </Link>
          <Link className="text-black/50" href="/asdasd">
            Endirimli
          </Link>
        </div>
        {/* When i deleted this div section problem is fixed */}


        <input type="text" placeholder="text" />

      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

I've searched all forums since yesterday. I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Could you try using 'use-client' at the top fo your file if your component is a client side component?

Comment: @saguirrews I separated the input element another file as a component and added "use client", the same problem continues. But when I add use client of the whole page the page I placed above, there is no problem. =(

Comment: The 'use-client' should be used in pages. So adding it to the ProfilePage is correct. If you separate the input to a different component, you should keep the 'use-client' at the top of the file

Comment: I have similar problem, when starting the app just after installation. But for me it issues 3 errors:
https://ibb.co/9htBhh1
https://ibb.co/Vpqsjgg
https://ibb.co/hVY3ZJF

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs due to difference between the prerendered react tree and the react tree rendered in the browser.

Check the below link for more info
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

In my opinion, you may disable the pre-render by setting “use client” at the top of the file.